# linking with a pragma with g++

Tags: c++, linker, g++, pragma

In Visual C++, one may link to a library in the code itself by doing `#pragma comment (lib, "libname.lib")`. Is something similar possible in g++?

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to do that?

Comment: @Robert: Link based on #if defined(...); make it easier to include code without editing Makefiles, etc.

Comment: @Zan Lynx: That is true but only if you are using an annoying build system. I would reccomend using CMake because then you just need to add one, maybe two lines to the CMakeLists.txt file to do the exact same thing. That's what I do instead. Do you have any build tool restrictions?

Comment: Boost uses this to do Auto-linking on Windows, which initially is quite nice (even when using CMake), but becomes quite a nusiance for installing and deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Boost Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_for_libraries_with_separate_source_code.automatic_library_selection) library has some support for autolinking, using the relevant compiler-specific code for the particular compiler. However, the docs note that the GCC toolchain [doesn't support autolinking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#auto-linking):

> Auto-Linking
>
> Most Windows compilers and linkers
>   have so-called “auto-linking support,”
>   which eliminates the second challenge.
>   Special code in Boost header files
>   detects your compiler options and uses
>   that information to encode the name of
>   the correct library into your object
>   files; the linker selects the library
>   with that name from the directories
>   you've told it to search.
>
> The GCC toolchains (Cygwin and MinGW)
>   are notable exceptions; GCC users
>   should refer to the linking
>   instructions for Unix variant OSes for
>   the appropriate command-line options
>   to use.